# How should I change the woocommerce_form_field HTML Structure?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I'm using [WooCommerce: Add Checkout Fees Based on Custom Radio Button](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-checkout-fees-based-on-radio-button-choice-ajax/) from businessbloomer

My question is about `woocommerce_form_field()` which is used in part 1

```php
// etc...
echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
echo '<h3>Customize Your Order!</h3>';
woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
echo '</div>';
// etc...
```

The structure of the HTML that `woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );` outputs is

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide update_totals_on_change" id="radio_choice_field" data-priority="">
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"> 
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="0" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_0">
        <label for="radio_choice_0" class="radio ">No Option</label>
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="10" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_10">
        <label for="radio_choice_10" class="radio ">Option 1 ($10)</label>
        <input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="30" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_30" checked="checked">
        <label for="radio_choice_30" class="radio ">Option 2 ($30)</label> 
    </span>
</p>
```

The structure that I'm trying to get is this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <!-- here every element which is gonna be type radio needs to be with It's label in a <li> element -->

        <li>
            <input type='radio'> </input>
            <label>No option</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type='radio'> </input>
            <label>Option 2</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type='radio'> </input>
            <label>Option 2</label>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

---

I searched for a solution but I could find one for the radio button

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To rewrite the output html from the `woocommerce_form_field` function there are 2 filter hooks available:

1. **Filter by type**: here we can specify the `$args['type']` like `text`, `password`, `datetime`, `select`, `radio`, etc...

```php
/**
 * Filter by type.
 */
$field = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_form_field_' . $args['type'], $field, $key, $args, $value );
```

2. **General filter on form fields**: a general filter where we can then add an if condition to apply this to a specific type of field

```php
/**
 * General filter on form fields.
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 */
$field = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_form_field', $field, $key, $args, $value );
```

---

The first option seems most suitable for your question

So

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_form_field_' . $args['type']...
```

Is going to be ( Where `$args['type']` is equal to `radio` )

```
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_radio( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Do something
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_radio', 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_radio', 10, 4 );
```

The callback function uses `$field` which contains all HTML from `<p>` to the closing `</p>` HTML tag, so we have the ability to rewrite the entire output of this through our function

---

Source used for this answer: [wc-template-functions.php#L2847-L2850](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/d7b2207e75eedb4fb89249b81dcd42133e8ca616/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2847-L2850), note the use of `$args` with which the code can be dynamically constructed.

(This code was copied from `wc-template-functions.php` line 2847 - 2850)

```
foreach ( $args['options'] as $option_key => $option_text ) {
    $field .= '<input type="radio" class="input-radio ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '_' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '"' . checked( $value, $option_key, false ) . ' />';
    $field .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '_' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" class="radio ' . implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $option_text ) . '</label>';
}
```

---

So to answer your question: We get, based on the `$key` so that it is applied only for that specific piece

```
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_radio( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Based on key
    if ( $key == 'radio_choice' ) {
        if ( ! empty( $args['options'] ) ) {
            
            $field = '<div><ul>';
            
            foreach ( $args['options'] as $option_key => $option_text ) {
                $field .= '<li>';
                $field .= '<input type="radio" value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '_' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" />';
                $field .= '<label>' . esc_html( $option_text ) . '</label>';
                $field .= '</li>';
            }
            
            $field .= '</ul></div>';
        }
    }
    
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_radio', 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_radio', 10, 4 );
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_0">                                    
            <label>No Option</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="10" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_10">        
            <label>Option 1 ($10)</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="30" name="radio_choice" id="radio_choice_30">
            <label>Option 2 ($30)</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```