# How to add a additional paragraph under WooCommerce checkout country field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I'd like to add an anchor link below the Country Dropdown in Woocommerce checkout fields.

I use the code below, but unfortunately without the desired result

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_text','additional_paragraph_after_billing_country', 10, 4 );
function additional_paragraph_after_billing_country( $field, $key, $args, $value ){
    if ( is_checkout() && $key == 'billing_country' ) {
        $field .= '<p class="form-row sf_add hide-on-desktop hide-on-tablet"><a href="#SF">extra paragraph here</a></p>';
    }
    return $field;
}
```

---

Image for illustration:

[image]

---

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add additional paragraph under a country field, you should use the `woocommerce_form_field_country` hook
opposite `woocommerce_form_field_text`

More explanation can be found in: [How should I change the woocommerce_form_field HTML Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999062/11987538)

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_country( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Compare
    if ( is_checkout() && $key === 'billing_country' ) {
        $field .= '<p class="form-row sf_add hide-on-desktop hide-on-tablet"><a href="#SF">extra paragraph here</a></p>';
    }
    
    return $field;
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_country', 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_country', 10, 4 );
```