# Remove specific states on WooCommerce checkout BUT only in the shipping form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I have this code which remove some States from the Billing and Shipping form in the checkout page. It works fine.

I need to remove the State but JUST in the "shipping form". Then the removed 'states' should be shown in the 'billing form'

I guess I need to use another hook than 'woocommerce_states'. But no sure which one.

```php
function remove_my_states ($states) {
   unset ($states ['ES'] ['TF']);// tenerife
   unset ($states ['ES'] ['GC']);// gran canaria
   unset ($states ['ES'] ['CE']);// ceuta
   unset ($states ['ES'] ['ML']); // melilla
   unset ($states ['ES'] ['PM']); // baleares
   return $states;
   }
 
add_filter ('woocommerce_states', 'remove_my_states');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that obvious because with the current hook you are using you cannot distinguish between the fields. What you can do as a workaround is use the `woocommerce_form_field_$args['type']` filter hook.

The callback function uses `$field` which contains all HTML from `<p>` to the closing `</p>` HTML tag, so we have the ability to rewrite the entire output of this through our function.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_state( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Checkout page only
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) return $field;
    
    // Only for shipping
    if ( $key == 'shipping_state' ) {
        // Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string
        $field = str_replace( '<option value="CE" >Ceuta</option>', '', $field );
        $field = str_replace( '<option value="ML" >Melilla</option>', '', $field );
        $field = str_replace( '<option value="PM" >Baleares</option>', '', $field );
        // Etc..
    }
    
    // Do something
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_state', 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_state', 10, 4 );
```

Might come in handy: [/woocommerce/i18n/states.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b18e2437f482bbc05a2da49ef89221fd373d140a/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/states.php)

More info: [How should I change the woocommerce_form_field HTML Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999062/11987538)

Comment: Not working in my site. I assume that the Theme I am using might cause this code to fail. I use Flatsome theme. This is checkout page of my site http://t12.d523.dinaserver.com/finalizar-compra/

Comment: @JPashs You can always try it by using a default theme. I can't take into account plugins or themes that influence my answer, since there are 1000+ of them. You could also try [How to debug in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61740111/11987538). Regards

Comment: I try it with other themes, but it does not work. I thing that the problem is that the problem is that your code try to match an 'option' element. In the 'Twenty Twenty-Two' theme the States is a search box build with ul->li elments (not an 'select->option elements)
This is my site: https://latevabotiga.com/tienda/